# Laravel 5.6: config/logging.php file is missing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In the docs of Laravel 5.6 its stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#configuration) that one can config his logging channels in `config/logging.php`. I have updated from Larvel 5.5 to Laravel 5.6 but I could not find this config file.

Do I need to call a special artisan command for this or something like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This file didn't exist in 5.5.

You can find the original one [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/logging.php) and copy-paste it into your project.

There is a complete upgrade guide [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade).